# Load Game From Cloud Issue Unity C# in Some Case Execution Order

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, backend

I am creating a game with unity using a backend service gamespark. One of the backend service i use is for saving and loading the game from cloud. This is to prevent player data lose and could make a transfer device feature.

I have also use a local save which advice from gamesparks backend service support to save the game local in device and just load the save game cloud if local save game is not found.

But in here i got a problem which if local save game not found then use load cloud save game.
When i load game from gamespark backend using Load Event example in my backend there is : Load_Game event (here usually we could call it Load_Game Function But this is at backend service).
When load from event i got a problem from script running execution order. I have make an execution order but it seem not going well.

The problem is when script that has gamesparks load event Load_Game execute it take a time that make my execution order did not run well. So the game is not loaded well by execution order.

And then sometimes the game is not loaded from cloud backend service because of the bad wifi signal. When in this case, player will confuse why after transfer device the game is not loaded continues the previous game as well.

How to prevent or solve a case like this ? From your experience about making the game mobile what should i do in load game from local and load game from cloud ?

I have do like if login then load from local device if not found then load from cloud.
I have do if each change scene then load from local device if not found then load from cloud.

i have do each exit from scene save to local and if exit the game save to local and save to cloud.

Thanks
Dennis

Comment: First of all your game should not proceed until your download finishes for example your GameData or GameState which you will be getting as JSON string in response. Once you get it you can bind it with your class and proceed.